# Why won't template parameter pack be deduced to multiple type arguments in function call?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a class templated on a type parameter and parameter pack, and am confused about type-deduction of this type; while writing an output-streaming operator I discovered a parameter pack on `operator<<` will not match both the type and pack parameters for the template class:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct foo
{ /* ... */ };

template< class... Ts >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const foo<Ts...>& )
{
  return os << 42;
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << foo<int>();
}
```

This fails to compile on both gcc-4.7.2 and clang-3.0, so I guess I'm misunderstanding the rules here.

gcc says (where line 16 is the output stream call):

```
t.cpp:16:28: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40:0,
                 from t.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:600:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = foo<int>]’
```

and clang says:

```
t.cpp:16:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'foo<int>')
        std::cout << foo<int>();
        ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~

[--- snip: lots of non-viable candidates from standard library ---]

t.cpp:8:19: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Ts = <>]
    std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const foo<Ts...>& )
                  ^
```

Could someone please enlighten me as to why the parameter pack for `operator<<` cannot be deduced to be the type parameter *and* parameter pack for `foo`?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that your class has a single parameter and a parameter pack, whereas the function only has a parameter pack. It wouldn't work with nothing in the pack anyway, so you might as well have the separate parameter.

Comment: Is that the full error message from gcc? I get "sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'Ts ...' into a fixed-length argument list" first

Comment: Upgrade. Gcc 4.8 and Clang 3.3 are out.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, They are doesn't compile for me too. Looking in the standard now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: [It's even worse on GCC 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4b6e62cd2626acf31960e1a556c69e33-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59).

Comment: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html you get gcc 4.8.1. linked from [here](http://isocpp.org/get-started)

Comment: @chris - might as well, maybe. But I'd rather not :) and I'd like to understand _why_.

Comment: @doctorlove - yes that's all gcc gives me. Are you on 4.7.2? Earlier versions had issues with variadics AFAIR.

Comment: @Potatoswatter & Koushik Suggesting an upgrade is unhelpful unless this is a compiler bug, which is why I tested with 2 compilers.

Comment: @doctorlove, that "sorry, unimplemented" is GCC 4.6, it's fixed in 4.7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is happening is that a template function with a template parameter pack `class... Ts`, and a parameter type (P) of `foo<Ts...>` is being deduced against an argument type (A) of `foo<int>`.

14.8.2.5/9 says of this:

> If P has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>` [it does], then each argument Pi [`Ts...`] of the respective template argument list
>   P is compared with the corresponding argument Ai [`int`] of the corresponding template argument list of A. If
>   the template argument list of P contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the
>   entire template argument list is a non-deduced context. [the pack expansion is last, so the previous doesnt apply] **If Pi is a pack expansion [`Ts...`, it is], then the pattern of Pi
>   is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of A (`int`). Each comparison deduces
>   template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by Pi.**

So `class... Ts` should be deduced as the one element list `int`, and consequently the function template should be instantiated with the parameter type `const foo<int>&`, and be viable.

It is a compiler bug.  Your code is well-formed.

More succinctly this is well-formed:

```
template<class A, class... B> struct S { };

template<class... C> void f(S<C...>) { }

int main() { f(S<int>()); }
```

but fails similarly on at least gcc 4.7.2 with:

```
 error: parameter 1 of ‘void f(S<C ...>) [with C = {int, C}]’
        has incomplete type ‘S<int, C>’
```

`C` is incorrectly deduced as `C = {int, C}` (a nonsensical recursion) instead of `C = {int}`.  The broken deduction of `C` leads to further garbage that `S<int, C>` has an incomplete type.

Comment: I think the OP knows this; the question is _why_?

Comment: Neither do I, though I find the wording for variadic templates to be particularly painful and generally try to avoid it wherever possible.

Comment: @user1131467 As a suggestion, use different names for the two `Ts`, the error message might be less arcane. :)

Comment: pretty bad bug. overcoming this requires using template<class... B> struct S { }; instead of template<class A, class... B> struct S { };

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I would have thought this was fixed already, but it still doesn't work in prerelease GCC 4.9 and Clang 3.4 builds (courtesy [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)).

The workaround is simple: use partial specialization to deduce the template arguments elsewhere.

```
template<class... Ts>
struct foo; // unimplemented

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct foo< T, Ts ... > // specialization for at least one argument
{ /* ... */ };

template< class... Ts >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const foo<Ts...>& )
{
  return os << 42;
}
```

Why *both* GCC and Clang can't solve this years-old bug by imitating the workaround in the general case, I don't know. The compiler vendors are perhaps facing an unfortunate choice between performance and correctness.